# How to post Text and image URL in one tweet using twitter API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am using Twitter API Client for node (REST & Streaming API)
https://github.com/ttezel/twit#tgetpath-params-callback

I am using twit API with nodejs
I need status(text) and URL to be displayed in one tweet.But it is getting URL and text as Two different tweets.

Comment: var secret = {
  consumer_key: '',  consumer_secret: '',  access_token_key: '',access_token_secret: ''
}
var Twitter = new TwitterPackage(secret);
Twitter.post('statuses/update', {status: 'http://www.twitter.com '}, function(error, tweet, response){
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(tweet);  
  console.log(response);  
});
Twitter.post('statuses/update', {status: 'Thanks to twitter'}, function(error, tweet, response){
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(tweet);  
  console.log(response);  
});

Comment: I am getting URl as one tweet and status as other tweet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is posting two Tweets because that's what you're telling it to do.  I've spaced out your code as best I can.

Here you set up the authentication:

```
var secret = { consumer_key: '', consumer_secret: '', access_token_key: '',access_token_secret: '' }
```

Here you create a twitter object:

```
var Twitter = new TwitterPackage(secret);
```

Here you send a Tweet with the text "twitter.com"

```
Twitter.post('statuses/update', 
    {status: 'twitter.com '}, 
    function(error, tweet, response){ 
       if(error){ console.log(error);} 
          console.log(tweet); 
          console.log(response); 
       }
);
```

Here you send *another* Tweet. This time with the text "Thanks to twitter":

```
Twitter.post('statuses/update', 
   {status: 'Thanks to twitter'}, 
   function(error, tweet, response){ 
      if(error){ console.log(error); } 
      console.log(tweet); 
      console.log(response); 
   }
);
```

If you only want to send **one** Tweet - you need to put the text and the link in the *same* status.  For example:

```
Twitter.post('statuses/update', 
   {status: 'Here is a link - https://example.com'}, 
   function(error, tweet, response){ 
      if(error){ console.log(error); } 
         console.log(tweet); 
         console.log(response); 
   }
);
```

Comment: How to set  3 parameters url,image,text in the post

Comment: Thanks Eden. Its workinf for me with url and text. How is it possible to set another parameter image along with url and text

Comment: Was does the documentation say? Post another question showing what you've tried and where it has failed.